# Alignment and the STL in VS 2012/VC11

Tags: c++, stl, alignment, visual-studio-2012

I have a vague memory of the STL having trouble with aligned structs (e.g. SIMD vectors placed in a std::vector), unless you specify a custom allocator.

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) document VS 2012/VC11 has partial support for [c++ alignment](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2341.pdf). Does this mean that the VS STL implementation can handle aligned structs now, without providing a custom allocator?

Comment: Probably not. The problem with SIMD types is that they require over-alignment - an alignment larger than the size of the type itself.

Comment: @Bo Persson The alignment requirement is equal to the size of the type for SIMD types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It means that the VC++ compiler supports a method for specifying the required alignment for a type (the `__declspec(align(N))` syntax). VC++ has always supported that, and it is basically listed as "partial" because "we have some alignment-related functionality, and it looks better than saying "not supported".

Apart from that, I'm not aware of anything in the C++11 alignment specification which indicates that SIMD vectors in a standard library container is guaranteed to work. C++11 alignment is basically just a formalization of what compilers already did, in this regard (as far as I know. I'd love if you could prove me wrong).

SIMD vectors are what the standard calls "over-aligned types" (see the part about "extended alignment"). What that means is basically "we guarantee nothing, and it's entirely up to the compiler how/if they handle such types.

In other words, implementing this part of C++11 would not necessarily change how SIMD objects are handled.

Comment: I'm aware of the __declspec(align(N)) syntax. I thought it was a VS specific thing and there is now a new c++ standard for this so you can write alignas(N) instead. Is that not so?

Comment: That specific syntax is VS specific. But other compilers have equivalent syntax (GCC has `__attribute__(align(N))`, I think it is). You are correct, C++11 replaces these with common syntax, such as `alignas`, but VS doesn't support those. That's why they say "partial": "we can do the same thing, you just have to use our custom syntax"

Comment: @B_old See [`alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas). May not be supported by all compilers yet though.

Comment: Indeed that *"partial"* is perfect rubbish. In fact they also have *"partial"* support for `std::isnan` and `<cfenv>`, but well.