# Do (visual) C++ STL containers respect __declspec(align(n))?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, alignment

using vectors of SIMD in optimized win32 release gives me (vector) the problem that I can align the vector; but since it has 3 pointers (each 4 bytes) overhead, the data will not properly align on 16 byte boundaries.
This could be a mistake on my part or normal (but to me regrettable) behavior or a bug.
Any advice about declaring a vector of 16 byte aligned structs?
No more segfaults... (versions tested: 2013 and 2015)
Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Did you actually check `sizeof(vector<T>)`? Last time I looked, the MSVC implementation doesn't make use of empty base optimization for the allocator, and you end up with a 32 byte `vector` on x64. Also, you care about the `vector`'s data buffer being 16-byte aligned, don't you? Not the `vector` itself.

Comment: There is a negative answer for an older version. Don't think it has changed since. [Alignment and the STL in VS 2012/VC11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815647/alignment-and-the-stl-in-vs-2012-vc11?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the superfast help, pointing me to docs and earlier questions!